# Run Elevate Zoom in a Modal

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering if it is possible to run this elevate zoom plug in from with in a modal.
I don't have the knowlegde to do this and just need a yes or no answer to this question.
Nobody here has been able to help me with this and I don't know if it can be done.
If not, I will try something else. If it can be done I will hire someone to get the job done.

Thanks guys.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Zoom Demo</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">   

<script src="jquery zoom-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="query.elevatezoom.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica-Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; }
        .link { display:block; margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 33px; color: #06f; }
    </style>

</head>


<body>

    <a href="#" class="link" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">
        Image
    </a>


    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h4>ASENCIO ART GOES HERE</h4>
        <img id="zoom_mw" src="housesmall.jpg" data-zoom-image="houselarge.jpg" alt=""/>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready( function() {
   $("#zoom_mw").elevateZoom({gallery:'#myModal',
   galleryActiveClass: 'active',
   scrollZoom : true,
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: It would appear that "elevateZoom" is a 3rd party plugin described here: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

Comment: That is correct. It is a third party plug in. That is why I wonder if this can be accomplished. Thank you.